# Interleaving array_agg in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres query in which I want to interleave my array_agg statements :

```
SELECT client_user_id, 
       (array_agg(question), array_agg(client_intake_question_id), array_agg(answer)) as answer 
FROM client_intake_answer
LEFT OUTER JOIN client_intake_question 
ON       client_intake_question.id = client_user_id
GROUP BY client_user_id
```

Gives me the following:

```
 5 | ("{""Have you ever received counselling?"",""Have you ever received counselling or mental health support in the past?""}","{1,2}","{yes,no}")
```

I would like the results to be:

```
  5 | ("{""Have you ever received counselling?", 1, "yes"",""Have you ever received counselling or mental health support in the past?", 2, "no""}"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set up a small example similar to yours:

> ```
> create table answers(user_id int, question_id int, answer varchar(20));
> create table questions(question_id int, question varchar(20));
>
> insert into questions values
> (1, 'question 1'),
> (2, 'question 2');
>
> insert into answers values
> (1, 1, 'yes'),
> (1, 2, 'no'),
> (2, 1, 'no'),
> (2, 2, 'yes');
> ```

> ```
> select user_id, array_agg(concat(questions.question, ',',  questions.question_id::text, ',', answers.answer))
> from   questions
> inner join answers
> on     questions.question_id = answers.question_id
> group by answers.user_id
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | array_agg                             
> ------: | :-------------------------------------
>       1 | {"question 1,1,yes","question 2,2,no"}
>       2 | {"question 1,1,no","question 2,2,yes"}
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c31f8b7985d2ea4ca9a3e16e9a3eeeff)*

Comment: Thank you! Better then my solution for sure.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

To interleave or splice together multiple array_agg's you can do the following:

```
SELECT client_user_id, 
   array_agg('[' || client_intake_question_id || question || ',' || answer || ']') as answer 
FROM client_intake_answer
LEFT OUTER JOIN
client_intake_question ON  client_intake_question.id = client_user_id
GROUP BY client_user_id
```